# React-Native/Firebase Insert and sort by timestamp

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, ecmascript-6

I've been working in react-native recently as I'm building a basic app where you can have a list of gigs, each having an associated date which is inserted into firebase as a timestamp.

I wanted to check but what's the best approach to sorting an array by date so that the list displays with the most recent please?

```
componentWillMount() {
    this.props.gigsFetch();

    this.createDataSource(this.props);
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.createDataSource(nextProps);
}

createDataSource({ gigs }) {
    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({
        rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2
    });

    this.dataSource = ds.cloneWithRows(gigs);
}


const mapStateToProps = state => {

    const sortedGigs = _.sortBy(state.gigs, 'date');

    const gigs = _.map(sortedGigs, (val, uid) => {
        return { ...val, uid };
    });

    return { gigs };
};
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

let firebase do this, use the firebase query

for ex:
say you want to show the latest 10 gigs

```
firebase.database().ref('gigs/').orderByChild('date').limitToLast(10);
```

check the limitToFirst and limitToLast parts of the documentation
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data

Comment: how do I sort by descending?